# How can i get the href while using cheerio

Tags: typescript, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to have the link while using cheerio with this code.

```
<div class="someClass">
    <a href="someLink">Link</a>
</div>
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
let link = $('.someClass a href').text();
```

Comment: Probably css selector i wrong. Shouldn't it be `let link = $('.someClass > a').text();`

Comment: @SilvanBregy No. It's not wrong. if two elements separated by space char in CSS selector (`node1 node2`)  it means that one want to select *descendant* node. In case separation by `>` char (`node1 > node2`) - one want to select *child* node. In current case it doesn't really matter which one to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to extract *node text from attribute* and it is not correct approach. If you want to extract *attribute value* try

```
let link = $('.someClass a').attr('href');
```